# How do we get/define filters in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, deep-learning

How to implement a deep autoencoder (eHow do i obtain filters from convulutional neural network(CNN)? My idea is something like this: Do random images of the input images (28x28) and get random patches (8x8). Then use autoencoders to learn the common features of the patches (features = hidden units; approximately 100, for example). Then apply features filters to the input images and do convolution. Am I correct?

I am confused because sometime the literature state only using like, e.g. 8, filters, but in my case I have 100..g. 2 or 3 layers)? Any ideas or resources?

Comment: I want to help, but I need to understand a little bit more about your question. Are you asking **how to choose the number of filters per layer?** Or, what code to use to **learn the filters?** Or something else?

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the tutorial : http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial

This is like a lecture on both auto-encoders and some simple stuff about CNN (convolution and pooling). When you complete this tutorial you will have both auto-encoder implementation and stacked-auto-encoder in your words deep auto-encoder implementation ready.

This tutorial will have exactly what you ask for:

- 28x28 MNIST images
- getting 8x8 patches and learning filters using auto-encoders
- convolving these images by these 8x8 filters
- pooling them
- using the pooled vectors/images and putting them in a soft-max classifier to learn 10 different classes of MNIST database.

Comment: So I can add this --> I ended up with the followin Deep Network:

Comment: Layer1 convolve with 32 filters of size 3by3 and sigmoid function for non-linearity/  Layer2 subsampling or inotherwords pooling with 2by2/Layer 3 convolve with 32 filters of 2by2 and sigmoid again/ Layer4 subsample with 2by2 / Layer 5 softmax classifier. This gives me over %98 according to random initialization of weights. I will try bigger convolution sizes and less filter counts and let you know the result in 2 weeks. But I can tell you that without using CNN and just using autoencoders and softmax layer at the end I can never reach %97-stuck at 96

Comment: I had 5 layers as mentioned above.. but if I have a bigger filter size I think I won't be able to have more than 1 convolution and 1 pooling.. maybe I can have 1 more fully connected autoencoder before last softmax layer.